# osxmetadata broken on MacOS

Tags: python, macos

All of a sudden osxmetadata is broken, it's been working fine for months and now I'm getting the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osxmetadata'` error.  When trying to install via pip I get build errors (see below) for xattr which apparently is a requirement for osxmetadata.

How would I find out how the module is now missing?  How can I find out what's changed?

I'm using Mohave 10.14.6 and Python 3.9.1.

The module's repository is here:
https://pypi.org/project/osxmetadata/

Any advice appreciated.

```
Tethys:~ debra$ pip3 install osxmetadata
Collecting osxmetadata
  Using cached osxmetadata-0.99.14-py3-none-any.whl (41 kB)
Collecting bitstring==3.1.7
  Using cached bitstring-3.1.7-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting py-applescript==1.0.2
  Using cached py_applescript-1.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_AppleScriptObjC-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.9 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-core==7.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from osxmetadata) (7.2)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit==7.2
  Using cached pyobjc_framework_AppleScriptKit-7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.8 kB)
Collecting xattr==0.9.7
  Using cached xattr-0.9.7.tar.gz (13 kB)
Collecting click>=7.0
  Using cached click-8.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-Cocoa>=7.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit==7.2->osxmetadata) (7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from xattr==0.9.7->osxmetadata) (1.14.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from cffi>=1.0.0->xattr==0.9.7->osxmetadata) (2.20)
Building wheels for collected packages: xattr
  Building wheel for xattr (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/0n/32xl4kh15db60dkknjlsx76r0000gr/T/pip-install-hfwc86ib/xattr_3ef19955dd0a44e2acb6e2140161dc5c/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/0n/32xl4kh15db60dkknjlsx76r0000gr/T/pip-install-hfwc86ib/xattr_3ef19955dd0a44e2acb6e2140161dc5c/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/0n/32xl4kh15db60dkknjlsx76r0000gr/T/pip-wheel-o2d733rw
       cwd: /private/var/folders/0n/32xl4kh15db60dkknjlsx76r0000gr/T/pip-install-hfwc86ib/xattr_3ef19955dd0a44e2acb6e2140161dc5c/
  Complete output (24 lines):
  Warning: 'classifiers' should be a list, got type 'filter'
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/xattr
  copying xattr/lib_build.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/xattr
  copying xattr/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/xattr
  copying xattr/lib.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/xattr
  copying xattr/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/xattr
  copying xattr/tool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/xattr
  copying xattr/pyxattr_compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/xattr
  running build_ext
  generating cffi module 'build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/_lib.c'
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9
  building '_lib' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/build
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/_lib.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/_lib.o
  xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Volumes/Archive/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist
  Use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the standalone command line developer tools.
  See `man xcode-select` for more details.
  error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for xattr
  Running setup.py clean for xattr
Failed to build xattr
Installing collected packages: xattr, pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC, pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit, py-applescript, click, bitstring, osxmetadata
    Running setup.py install for xattr ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/0n/32xl4kh15db60dkknjlsx76r0000gr/T/pip-install-hfwc86ib/xattr_3ef19955dd0a44e2acb6e2140161dc5c/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/0n/32xl4kh15db60dkknjlsx76r0000gr/T/pip-install-hfwc86ib/xattr_3ef19955dd0a44e2acb6e2140161dc5c/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/0n/32xl4kh15db60dkknjlsx76r0000gr/T/pip-record-zazdtdsf/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.9/xattr
         cwd: /private/var/folders/0n/32xl4kh15db60dkknjlsx76r0000gr/T/pip-install-hfwc86ib/xattr_3ef19955dd0a44e2acb6e2140161dc5c/
    Complete output (24 lines):
    Warning: 'classifiers' should be a list, got type 'filter'
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/xattr
    copying xattr/lib_build.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/xattr
    copying xattr/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/xattr
    copying xattr/lib.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/xattr
    copying xattr/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/xattr
    copying xattr/tool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/xattr
    copying xattr/pyxattr_compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/xattr
    running build_ext
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/_lib.c'
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9
    building '_lib' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/build
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/_lib.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/_lib.o
    xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Volumes/Archive/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist
    Use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the standalone command line developer tools.
    See `man xcode-select` for more details.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/0n/32xl4kh15db60dkknjlsx76r0000gr/T/pip-install-hfwc86ib/xattr_3ef19955dd0a44e2acb6e2140161dc5c/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/0n/32xl4kh15db60dkknjlsx76r0000gr/T/pip-install-hfwc86ib/xattr_3ef19955dd0a44e2acb6e2140161dc5c/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/0n/32xl4kh15db60dkknjlsx76r0000gr/T/pip-record-zazdtdsf/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.9/xattr Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

From the developer:

It looks like xattr, which needs to be built, is having issues with xcode and that you have a beta version of xcode installed which could be causing the issue.

xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Volumes/Archive/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist

The following commands might be helpful:

```
$ sudo xcode-select -r
$ sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
Then:
$ sudo xcode-select -p
to validate that the command line tools path is correct
```